# how do I setup logging to the local hard drive with Rabbit-mq client?

Tags: c#, logging, rabbitmq

Is there a way to ***programmatically*** turn on logging to the local hard drive ?

(eg: log to file C:\temp\Rabbit.log )

(( of course the directory and name will change ))

In other words, I want to be able to turn logging on (or off) when I create the Rabbit MQ connection...

Background:
RabbitMQ is being used from a reference within my application

In Visual Studio, right click on "References", via NuGet

```
add reference : RabbitMQ.Client.dll (v4.0.30319)
```

Here is my code that runs the client side of Rabbit MQ.
(the message processing code has been removed )

```
using RabbitMQ.Client;
using RabbitMQ.Client.Events;
using RabbitMQ.Client.MessagePatterns;

private void Internal_Run(CancellationToken cancelToken)
{
    var connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();

    // I know this is wrong... but this is what I would ***like*** to do:
    // connectionFactory.IsLogging = true;
    // connectionFactory.LogPathAndFile = "C:\\Temp\\Rabbit.log";


    connectionFactory.HostName = "My Host";
    connectionFactory.UserName = "My userName";
    connectionFactory.Password = "My password";
    string QueueName = "My unique queue name";

    try
    {
        using (IConnection connection = connectionFactory.CreateConnection())
        {
            using (IModel model = connection.CreateModel())
            {
                //Note declare the queue here, as well. Because we might start the receiver before the sender, 
                // we want to make sure the queue exists before we try to consume messages from it
                model.QueueDeclare(queue: QueueName, durable: true, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);
                var subscription = new Subscription(model, QueueName, false);

                int milisecondTimeOut_RabbitMQ = 500;
                while (true)
                {
                    BasicDeliverEventArgs basicDeliveryEventArgs;
                    if (subscription.Next(milisecondTimeOut_RabbitMQ, out basicDeliveryEventArgs))
                    {
                        if (basicDeliveryEventArgs == null)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        if (basicDeliveryEventArgs.Body.Length == 0)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }

                        string messageContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(basicDeliveryEventArgs.Body);

                        subscription.Ack(basicDeliveryEventArgs);  // send the ACK back to queue to let Rabbit know I processed the message
                    }

                    if (cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException oce)
    {
        // this is an expected cancellation - program shutting down
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A custom NLOG configuration file must be created.  Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  autoReload="true"
  throwExceptions="false">

<variable name="AppName" value="ManagerService" />
<variable name="LogDir" value="Logs" />

<variable name="logFormat_File" value="[${longdate}][${logger}] 
[${message}${onexception:${newline}EXCEPTION\: ${exception:format=ToString}}]"/>
<variable name="logFormat_Console" value="${longdate} | ${logger} | 
${level:uppercase=true} | ${message}"/>
<variable name="logFormat_Debugger" value="[${logger}] '${message}'"/>

<targets async="true">

<target xsi:type="File"
        name="Log_Main"
        layout="${logFormat_File}"
        fileName="${basedir}${LogDir}\Main.log"
        keepFileOpen="false"
        archiveFileName="${basedir}${LogDir}\Main_${shortdate}.{##}.bak"
        archiveNumbering="Sequence"
        archiveEvery="Day"
        maxArchiveFiles="30"
        />

    <target xsi:type="File"
        name="Log_Timing"
        layout="${logFormat_File}"
        fileName="${basedir}${LogDir}\Timing.log"
        keepFileOpen="false"
        archiveFileName="${basedir}${LogDir}\Timing_${shortdate}.{##}.bak"
        archiveNumbering="Sequence"
        archiveEvery="Day"
        maxArchiveFiles="30"
        />

        <target xsi:type="File"
        name="Log_Trans"
        layout="${logFormat_File}"
        fileName="${basedir}${LogDir}\Trans.log"
        keepFileOpen="false"
        archiveFileName="${basedir}${LogDir}\Trans_${shortdate}.{##}.bak"
        archiveNumbering="Sequence"
        archiveEvery="Day"
        maxArchiveFiles="30"
        />


        <target xsi:type="File"
        name="Error_Log"
        layout="${logFormat_File}"
        fileName="${basedir}${LogDir}\Error.log"
        keepFileOpen="false"
        archiveFileName="${basedir}${LogDir}\Error_${shortdate}.{##}.bak"
        archiveNumbering="Sequence"
        archiveEvery="Day"
        maxArchiveFiles="30"
        />

        <target xsi:type="File"
        name="Warn_Log"
        layout="${logFormat_File}"
        fileName="${basedir}${LogDir}\Warn.log"
        keepFileOpen="false"
        archiveFileName="${basedir}${LogDir}\Warn_${shortdate}.{##}.bak"
        archiveNumbering="Sequence"
        archiveEvery="Day"
        maxArchiveFiles="30"
        />

        <target xsi:type="File"
        name="DB_Log"
        layout="${logFormat_File}"
        fileName="${basedir}${LogDir}\DB.log"
        keepFileOpen="false"
        archiveFileName="${basedir}${LogDir}\DB_${shortdate}.{##}.bak"
        archiveNumbering="Sequence"
        archiveEvery="Day"
        maxArchiveFiles="30"
        />

        <target xsi:type="File"
        name="MQ_Log"
        layout="${logFormat_File}"
        fileName="${basedir}${LogDir}\MQ.log"
        keepFileOpen="false"
        archiveFileName="${basedir}${LogDir}\MQ_${shortdate}.{##}.bak"
        archiveNumbering="Sequence"
        archiveEvery="Day"
        maxArchiveFiles="30"
        />

        <target xsi:type="File"
        name="Rest_Log"
        layout="${logFormat_File}"
        fileName="${basedir}${LogDir}\Rest.log"
        keepFileOpen="false"
        archiveFileName="${basedir}${LogDir}\Rest_${shortdate}.{##}.bak"
        archiveNumbering="Sequence"
        archiveEvery="Day"
        maxArchiveFiles="30"
        />

        <target xsi:type="File"
        name="BM_Log"
        layout="${logFormat_File}"
        fileName="${basedir}${LogDir}\BM.log"
        keepFileOpen="false"
        archiveFileName="${basedir}${LogDir}\BM_${shortdate}.{##}.bak"
        archiveNumbering="Sequence"
        archiveEvery="Day"
        maxArchiveFiles="30"
        />


<target xsi:type="EventLog"
        name="eventlog"
        source="CetrusManagerService"
        log="Cetrus"
        layout="${message}${newline}${exception:format=ToString}"/>

<target name="debugger" xsi:type="Debugger" layout="${logFormat_Debugger}"/>

<target name="console" xsi:type="Console" layout="${logFormat_Console}" />

</targets>


<rules>
<logger name="Manager.Calls.Manager" writeTo="Log_Main" level="Info" />

<logger name="Manager.Calls.Rest" writeTo="Rest_Log" levels="Info,Error" />

<logger name="Manager.Timing.*" writeTo="Log_Timing" level="Info" />

<logger name="Manager.TransactionProcessor.*" writeTo="Log_Trans" levels="Info,Warn,Error" />

<logger name="Manager.Calls.DB" writeTo="DB_Log" levels="Info,Error" />

<logger name="Manager.Calls.MessageQueue" writeTo="MQ_Log" level="Info" />

<logger name="Manager.Calls.BinaryManager" writeTo="BM_Log" level="Info" />

<logger name="*" writeTo="Error_Log" level="Error" />

<logger name="*" writeTo="Warn_Log" level="Warn" />

<logger name="*" writeTo="eventlog" minlevel="Error" />

<logger name="*" writeTo="debugger" minlevel="Trace" />

<logger name="*" writeTo="console" minlevel="Info" />

</rules>

</nlog>
```